# Permission denied error when pasting multiple images to pptx in a loop

Tags: python, image, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am pasting a bunch of images (50+) into an existing PowerPoint File, slide by slide. After a quite randomly number of slides (usually between 10-20) I get an permission Error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:/Users/PowerPointFileName.pptx'

My Code looks something like this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
import os
import time

def insert_into_ppt(FileName, slide_nr, img):
    prs = Presentation(FileName)
    slide = prs.slides[slide_nr]
    slide.shapes.add_picture(img, 2, 5)
    prs.save(FileName)
    time.sleep(1)
    
images = os.listdir('picture folder')
for i, img in enumerate(images): 
    insert_into_ppt('PowerPointFileName.pptx', i, img)
```

at first I thought the saving and opening again apart might be to fast, but even adding `time.sleep(5)` in there won't fix the issue.
Do you have any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: Why are you opening and saving for each file, as opposed to saving once after all images have been inserted?

Comment: what treuss said .. Also, you are not closing the file, just saving.

Comment: Yeah that was probably it, as the file was growing larger and larger with each iteration. Instead of passing the filename I am now passing the actual Presentation Object. So it's only initilized once.
@rasjani I think with pptx you don't have to close the files, they are not really opened